# Instant.now() different results in VM

Tags: java, linux, sockets, server, client

> I am trying to measure the ping of a socket connection.
>
> Like so;
>
> Server: Sends ping to client
>
> Client: Receives ping and encodes current time as response
>
> Server: Decode response and calculate ping as = current time -
> response time
>
> In theory this should tell me a fairly accurate measurement of the
> amount of time it takes for data to transfer from the client ->
> server.
>
> The ISSUE is the encoded time (millis) from the client (linux VM) is
> ~4s before the time cached on the server when sending the ping.
>
> It would appear that Instant.now() is returning inconsistent results
> across machines.
>
> I've confirmed this by simply outputting Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
>
> Running both test at the "same time", the time on the VM is several
> seconds behind? What is going on here?

Comment: *"What is going on here?"* One or both of the machines' hardware clocks are wrong; i.e. not synced with an accurate time source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @aatwork for your information, I've solved my problem.

The issue has come from my lack of understanding of how time and UTC works on a global scale and that any induvial machine will likely have an offset.

To correct for this, one should poll the time from an [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) server. Doing so will allow for synchronized results across multiple machines.

[Querying NTP Server in Java](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-query-the-nist-internet-time-service-using-the-network-time-protocol.html)

[Dependency: Apache Commons Net](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/3.6)

[List of Top Public Time Servers](https://gist.github.com/mutin-sa/eea1c396b1e610a2da1e5550d94b0453)

Answer (score 6):

VM takes server time by default. So you need to check the time set on your server machine.

Basically server & client are two different machines. Time in these two machines are not in sync. You need to check both machine time & rectify where it is not correct.
**This has nothing to do with Java.**